# Regular expression for URLs in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following URLs

```
content/test
content/contact
products/
products/96_product/
products/96_product/86000_productdescription1
products/96_product/86343_productdescription3
products/96_product/76002_productdescription4
products/96_product/100222_productdescription5
products/100_product233/86303_productdescription1
products/100_product233/844543_productdescription3
products/100_product233/73442_productdescription4
products/100_product233/103434_productdescription5
```

I would need to get the product descriptions. The numbers can be 5 or 6 digits. How can I formulate a regular expression to get the product descriptions in a list?

Comment: lmgtfy... https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow :

```
[re.search('product\/([0-9]{5,6})_productdescription', s).group(1) 
 if re.search('product\/([0-9]{5,6})_productdescription', s)
 else '' 
 for s in urls]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `str.split()` to split on `'_'`, then take the last part:

```
descriptions = []
for url in urls:
    parts = url.split("_")
    if len(parts) == 3:
        descriptions.append(parts[-1])
```

For more complex cases you could use a regular expression like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"products/.*/\d{5,6}_(.*)")
descriptions = []
for url in urls:
    match = regex.match(url)
    if match:
        descriptions.append(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

regular expression

```
^.*\d{5,6}_([^\/])*$
```

explanation
`^` start
`.*` anything
`\d{5,6}` five or six digits
`_` underscore
`()` save this in the result
`[^\/]*` anything that is not a slash
`$` end

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html  python regular expression reference
http://tartley.com/?p=1349 regular expression pdf cheatsheet